# MODX Xparser может кто то пользуется, вопрос по парсингу

Tags: php, modx

Верю в силу сообщества и что кто то использует этот компонент для MODX.

если имею такую структуру

```
<div class="chairs_page_list"> <a href="/"> товар 1 </a> <a href="/"> товар 2 </a> .... </div>
```

Как мне правильно записать селектор записи для основного задания и парсить ссылку для подчиненного?

Comment: **кто то использует этот помпанент для Modx** CMSке 20й год стукнул) не слышал, чтоб сейчас такое вообще кто-то использовал) есть куча альтернативных сервисов на любой вкус) специфические задачи пишут на чем-то вроде laravel/symfony) либо вообще микросервисах) .... по последней строчке вопроса -  ничего не понятно... код нужно распарсить на ссылки `Array("url"=>"/", "name"=>"товар 1")` ?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Компонент очень удобный, можно парсить сотни тысяч страниц автоматом. Но вот этот момент. Я постараюсь ответить по подробнее. Я сначала задаю общий селектор записи, он же .chairs_page_list a, то есть он будет сканировать каждый товар как a, то есть все что внутри. Но мне нужно чтобы он перешел по ссылке для парса деталей товара. но он не может взять ссылку так как она уровнем выше.. Там есть возможность искать селектор с помощью css, xpach и регулярки